# 'g' is used uninitialized in this function [-Wuninitialized]

Tags: c, struct

Why I am getting error here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct abc{
   char a;char b;
};

int main (void) {

   struct abc def;
   __typeof__(def)* g;
   g->a = 'a'; //error line

   return 0;
}
```

That above is only a warning, but true error is `command terminated`. Do know why

Comment: It's telling exactly what's happening. You're using `g` uninitialized. `g` is a pointer that you dereference, but it's got some garbage value in it.

Comment: Please explain what `g` points to. Then explain how `g->a` is supposed to be assigned a value.

Comment: *"but true error is command terminated"* No, the true error is that 'g' is used uninitialized. You shouldn't even bother trying to run the code until you've fixed all of the warnings. To have the compiler help you with that, compile with `-Werror`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've defined `g` as a pointer to type `struct abc`, but you didn't set that pointer to point anywhere.  So when you attempt to dereference it by writing to `g->a` you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to make `g` point somewhere, probably to `def`.

```
__typeof__(def)* g = &def;
```